# Umbraco Courier gets a Soap Exception connecting to remote site

Tags: umbraco

So I am running an Umbraco site locally, and the same site on my live server. But I can't get Courier to work to transfer my data between the 2 (although I have had no issues in the past).

I am using an SQL CE database locally, and MSSQL for the live site (the Courier support team don't think this should be an issue).

Now the issue is not connecting between the sites, because my localhost connects to the live site, and passes across a package as you can see from the log below, but then it has an error extracting the package. In the browser, the pop-out window just goes blank, and never completes, but the log tells me the following report:

```
2016-02-04 09:27:34,215 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:34,215 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:36,703 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 44] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:40,561 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 56] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:40,562 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 56] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:40,562 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 56] Added PackagingTask behind queue of : 0
2016-02-04 09:27:40,562 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.BackgroundTaskRunner - [Thread 56]  Task added Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.PackagingTask
2016-02-04 09:27:40,562 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 25] Starting PackagingTask with id: dbdaaa27-12f0-453e-a272-ee86f42ee320
2016-02-04 09:27:40,562 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 25] Opening session: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
2016-02-04 09:27:40,563 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider - [Thread 25] Opening session to http://www.adamanthony.co.uk
2016-02-04 09:27:44,390 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Packaging.RevisionPackaging - [Thread 25] Document types: SkillItem hash-mismatch (local/remote) d1572093dd52efbce27132025a9b70f7 / 736e152936c2d2fbcf35e3f28c23b3bb
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 25] Disposing: True
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 25] Closing session: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateProvider - [Thread 25] Closing session, UseGlobalSession: False, key: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateGlobalSessionManager - [Thread 25] Closing session, IsInWebContext: False
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 25] Disposing: True
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 25] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,532 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 25] Completed PackagingTask with id: dbdaaa27-12f0-453e-a272-ee86f42ee320
2016-02-04 09:27:45,746 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,748 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,748 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,766 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 35] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,779 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 34] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:45,783 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 18] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:46,021 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 44] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 42] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 42] Unloading (count: 0)
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 42] Added ExtractionTask behind queue of : 0
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.BackgroundTaskRunner - [Thread 42]  Task added Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.ExtractionTask
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 22] Starting ExtractionTask with id: cba12ffe-c730-4e38-838d-2c278463332b
2016-02-04 09:27:47,958 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Running PopulateGraph
2016-02-04 09:27:47,959 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Finished PopulateGraph (took 2ms)
2016-02-04 09:27:47,959 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 22] Adding event DeleteContentAndMedia To Queue: DeploymentComplete for session: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3
2016-02-04 09:27:47,959 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Starting extraction
2016-02-04 09:27:47,959 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Opens database session
2016-02-04 09:27:47,959 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider - [Thread 22] Opening session to http://www.adamanthony.co.uk
2016-02-04 09:27:48,215 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Transfering pre-extraction files
2016-02-04 09:27:48,215 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Running ExtractReadyRevisionBatch
2016-02-04 09:27:48,215 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Extracting batch of 1 items
2016-02-04 09:27:48,215 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Extracting: AdamAnthony - Umbraco.Courier.Core.DependencyGraph+GraphNode
2016-02-04 09:27:48,441 [20] WARN  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Finished ExtractItem (took 230ms)
2016-02-04 09:27:48,441 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Finished ExtractReadyRevisionBatch (took 230ms)
2016-02-04 09:27:48,441 [20] ERROR Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] There was a problem with extracting database information for the item: Name:AdamAnthony | Id:Adamanthony | Provider:Document types
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A call to SetContextId must occur before getting/setting a context
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.GlobalExecutionContextManager.get_CurrentContext()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.GlobalExecutionContextManager.GetContext(Boolean createIfNoneExists)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Webservices.Repository.Extract(String sessionKey, Byte[] item, ItemIdentifier itemId, Boolean overwrite, String user, String pass)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.WebServiceProvider.RepositoryWebservice.Extract(String sessionKey, Byte[] item, ItemIdentifier itemId, Boolean overwrite, String user, String pass)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.ExtractItem(Item item, Boolean overwrite)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction.ExtractItem(GraphNode node, Boolean isDependency)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction.ExtractReadyRevisionBatch()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction.Extract()
2016-02-04 09:27:48,441 [20] INFO  Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction - [Thread 22] Rolling back changes due to errors
2016-02-04 09:27:48,809 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 22] Disposing: True
2016-02-04 09:27:48,809 [20] WARN  Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local - [Thread 22] Closing session called but there is no session open: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3
2016-02-04 09:27:49,502 [20] DEBUG Umbraco.Courier.Core.EventManager - [Thread 22] Unloading (count: 1)
2016-02-04 09:27:49,502 [20] ERROR Umbraco.Courier.Core.TaskManager - [Thread 22] Error ExtractionTask with id: cba12ffe-c730-4e38-838d-2c278463332b
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Tried opening session with id: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3. - There is already an active session with id: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a and there can only be one
   at Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateGlobalSessionManager.set_CurrentSessionId(String value)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateProvider.CloseSession(String key)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local.CloseSession(String key)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Webservices.Repository.CloseSession(String sessionKey, String username, String password)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.WebServiceProvider.RepositoryWebservice.CloseSession(String sessionKey, String username, String password)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.CloseSession(String sessionKey)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Common.Extensions.GlobalExtensions.DisposeIfDisposable(Object input)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Repository.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Repository.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BaseRevisionHandler.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BaseRevisionHandler.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.ExtractionTask.Run()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BackgroundTaskRunner`1.ConsumeTaskInternal(T task)
2016-02-04 09:27:49,502 [20] ERROR Umbraco.Courier.Core.BackgroundTaskRunner - [Thread 22] An error occurred consuming task
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Tried opening session with id: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3. - There is already an active session with id: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a and there can only be one
   at Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateGlobalSessionManager.set_CurrentSessionId(String value)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Persistence.V6.NHibernate.NHibernateProvider.CloseSession(String key)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Local.CloseSession(String key)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.Webservices.Repository.CloseSession(String sessionKey, String username, String password)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.WebServiceProvider.RepositoryWebservice.CloseSession(String sessionKey, String username, String password)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.CloseSession(String sessionKey)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.RepositoryProviders.CourierWebserviceRepositoryProvider.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Common.Extensions.GlobalExtensions.DisposeIfDisposable(Object input)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Repository.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Repository.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BaseRevisionHandler.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Extraction.RevisionExtraction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BaseRevisionHandler.Dispose()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.ExtractionTask.Run()
   at Umbraco.Courier.Core.BackgroundTaskRunner`1.ConsumeTaskInternal(T task)
```

Or to make this a little easier to read:

```
[Thread 56] Unloading (count: 0)
[Thread 56] Added PackagingTask behind queue of : 0
[Thread 56] Task added Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.PackagingTask
[Thread 25] Starting PackagingTask with id: dbdaaa27-12f0-453e-a272-ee86f42ee320
[Thread 25] Opening session: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
[Thread 25] Opening session to http://www.adamanthony.co.uk
[Thread 25] Document types: SkillItem hash-mismatch (local/remote) d1572093dd52efbce27132025a9b70f7 / 736e152936c2d2fbcf35e3f28c23b3bb
[Thread 25] Disposing: True
[Thread 25] Closing session: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
[Thread 25] Closing session, UseGlobalSession: False, key: 5d218615-ecf8-430d-8853-bf7b7a27299a
[Thread 25] Closing session, IsInWebContext: False
[Thread 25] Disposing: True
[Thread 25] Unloading (count: 0)
[Thread 25] Completed PackagingTask with id: dbdaaa27-12f0-453e-a272-ee86f42ee320
[Thread 42] Unloading (count: 0)
[Thread 42] Added ExtractionTask behind queue of : 0
[Thread 42]  Task added Umbraco.Courier.Core.Tasks.ExtractionTask
[Thread 22] Starting ExtractionTask with id: cba12ffe-c730-4e38-838d-2c278463332b
[Thread 22] Running PopulateGraph
[Thread 22] Finished PopulateGraph (took 2ms)
[Thread 22] Adding event DeleteContentAndMedia To Queue: DeploymentComplete for session: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3
[Thread 22] Starting extraction
[Thread 22] Opens database session
[Thread 22] Opening session to http://www.adamanthony.co.uk
[Thread 22] Transfering pre-extraction files
[Thread 22] Running ExtractReadyRevisionBatch
[Thread 22] Extracting batch of 1 items
[Thread 22] Extracting: AdamAnthony - Umbraco.Courier.Core.DependencyGraph+GraphNode
[Thread 22] Finished ExtractItem (took 230ms)
[Thread 22] Finished ExtractReadyRevisionBatch (took 230ms)
[Thread 22] There was a problem with extracting database information for the item: Name:AdamAnthony | Id:Adamanthony | Provider:Document types

    System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A call to SetContextId must occur before getting/setting a context

[Thread 22] Rolling back changes due to errors
[Thread 22] Disposing: True
[Thread 22] Closing session called but there is no session open: 8d502ccd-e4ea-49b1-a9b3-4159ea5a8fa3
[Thread 22] Unloading (count: 1)
```

Further info:

- My environment is a Rackspace Cloud Site
- Permissions are all set with the maximum freedom I can give
- My username and password are included in the courier.config file

I surely can't be the only one who has received this error? Anyone info on this would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Has the user you are using the same credentials in both databases?

Have you applied the Courier hotfix?

Have you tried rebooting your site and recycling the AppPool? It could be related to a stuck previous deployment.

Comment: Yeah tried all of these. In the end the only thing that worked was moving all my databases to mssql.